# Github GraphQL API - add / remove columns in a board

Tags: api, github, graphql

Is there a way to add or remove columns into a project board ?

It was possible with the former API but I can't see the equivalent with graphQL API:

```
POST /projects/{project_id}/columns
```

```
DELETE /projects/columns/{column_id}
```

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/projects/columns?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-project-column

I managed to obtained the default layout with 3 predefined columns but can't remove those and add mine.